# Compiling Simple static OpenGL 4.0 program using MinGW, freeglut and glew

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, freeglut, glew

The problem is in the title, I'll try to list what I've already tried and so on below.

First off, in my understanding, in order to use OpenGL 4.0 on windows you must extend and or bypass the default windows library as it only ships OpenGL 1.1.

So we have MinGW installed at `C:/MinGW/`. Next I setup FreeGLUT by downloading the [tarball](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeglut/files/freeglut/2.8.0/freeglut-2.8.0.tar.gz/download) from the [project site](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download). Extract and compile by running the makefiles according to the [instructions](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/install.php) with a minor addition of `--prefix` to the `./configure` command.

```
./configure --prefix=/c/Users/Owner/root/
make all
make install
```

Now I have freeglut in `/c/Users/Owner/root/lib/`, `/c/Users/Owner/root/include/` and so on. Next up is GLEW, my problem child as far as I can tell.

Download the source archive from [the project site](http://glew.sourceforge.net/index.html) ([direct 1.7.0.zip link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.7.0/glew-1.7.0.zip/download)). Compiling is a tad more complicated, my current recipe is derived from the stack overflow question " [Building glew on windows with mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005076/building-glew-on-with-mingw) ". An abbreviated form is listed below:

```
mkdir lib/
mkdir bin/
gcc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.o -c src/glew.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a -o lib/glew32.dll src/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
ar cr lib/libglew32.a src/glew.o
gcc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -DGLEW_MX -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.mx.o -c src/glew.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32mx.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32mx.dll.a -o lib/glew32mx.dll src/glew.mx.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
ar cr lib/libglew32mx.a src/glew.mx.o
```

and should be run from the "root" of `/path/to/glew-1.7.0/`.

---

Now with setup of libraries "done" (assuming no mistakes... ) compiling my simple program is done with this line.

```
${G++}  -DFREEGLUT_STATIC -DGLEW_STATIC -m32 main.cpp -o main.exe -lfreeglut_static -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lglew32  -I ${ROOTPATH}/include -L ${ROOTPATH}/lib --static
```

Now to decompose this a bit and walk through why I have various "extra" arguments and to show you what errors and problems I've already run into and solved.

1. `-DFREEGLUT_STATIC` and `-lfreeglut_static` are used instead of the normal `-lfreeglut` as we want a static build here. Failure to do this gives linker errors relating to freeglut.
2. `-DGLEW_STATIC` is added for the same reason.
3. `-lwinmm` is added to fix the linker error: `freeglut_init.c:(.text+0x5d9): undefined reference to '_timeBeginPeriod@4'`.
4. `-lgdi32` is added to fix the linker error: `c:/Users/Owner/root//lib\libfreeglut_static.a(freeglut_init.o):freeglut_init.c:(.text+0x58c): undefined reference to '_GetDeviceCaps@8'`

Now I'm stumped with the following linker error:

```
c:/Users/Owner/root//lib\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0x83e8): undefined reference to `_glGetString@4'
c:/Users/Owner/root//lib\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0xa1b2): undefined reference to `_glGetString@4'
c:/Users/Owner/root//lib\libglew32.a(glew.o):glew.c:(.text+0xa290): undefined reference to `_glGetString@4'
```

The minimal test case that produces this error (`main.cpp`) is.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Try adding -lopengl32 last on the line to compile your program and see if it helps. EDIT: Should probably be -lfreeglut_static as genpfault says, I read too quickly.

Comment: @Jite That works! (on the minimal test case) O.o Please make this an answer so I can upvote and accept it. I can't believe I managed to miss a combination of GCC args as I've tried about 12 different sets! Even better if you or someone else could provide some info on _how_ to choose the library order other than randomly trying combinations.

Comment: Glad it worked! I think someone else will have to explain it more deeply, but from what I understand, correct me if I'm wrong, it's about shadowing, like if you have two libraries define a function with the same name, the last one linked will over shadow the prior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding -lopengl32 last on the line to compile your program and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Argument order is significant with `gcc` linker options.

Try this:

```
${G++} -DFREEGLUT_STATIC -DGLEW_STATIC -m32 main.cpp -o main.exe -I ${ROOTPATH}/include -L ${ROOTPATH}/lib -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lglew32 -static -lfreeglut_static
```

Also, I don't think there's a double-dash `--static` option, just `-static`.

And on win32 you're going to need a successful `glewInit()` before your `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` function pointer will be valid.  After checking your core version and/or extension, of course :)

Comment: That adds more complaints about ` undefined reference to '_wglGetProcAddress@4'. Probably should have mentioned that I've played with the argument order. What I have in the question is the set of arguments that gives the least amount of GCC spam.

Comment: Seems like both `--static` and `-static` work. I used `--static` as is a longform option.

Comment: As far as `glewInit()` goes, yes I know. I put a *minimal* testcase that produced the linker error. I was afraid if I put 25 or 50 lines of C++ code, everyone would focus on the code. By reducing it down to just the 6 lines that produce the linker error, I seemed to have gotten a faster and more correct response. Btw the actual code works fine for me on linux ;). What actually solved my windows problem is moving `-lopengl32` to the end of the gcc argument list. See my comments below the question in response to Jite.