# GLEW fails to initialize

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, glew

My machine has OpenGL 2.0, for some weird reason, the header file `gl.h` does not contain shader functions. So, I was suggested to use GLEW. I installed GLEW properly, and have linked `glew32s` to my compiler, I have also included the header file in my `main.cpp`. Yet, I get compiler (not runtime) errors when simply calling:

```
 GLenum err = glewInit();
```

> undefined reference to `*imp*_glewInit@0'

What in the world is that supposed to mean? It says similar things for shader functions.

I am using the GCC compiler, and am on windows x86.

Comment: Are you `#define`ing `GLEW_STATIC` before `#include`ing `glew.h`?

Comment: If you're on Windows and not using VC++, I think you have to build Glew with gcc then link to that.  These two questions might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066673/installing-and-linking-glew-for-eclipse-cygwin-on-windows, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234386/compiling-simple-static-opengl-4-0-program-using-mingw-freeglut-and-glew

Comment: @genpfault Wow. That's all that was missing. thanks!

Comment: @pwny Are you sure about that? it seems to work fine now, thanks to genpfault's comment.

Comment: @DantheMan Not sure at all, it was a (not so) educated guess.  If it works now, all good for you :)

Comment: @pwny Ah ok. I don't get any compiler errors, but I do get a crash when calling `glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);` I guess I should build a gcc version?

Comment: @DantheMan I can't help that much without seeing the crash and fiddling a little but it seems to me that you'd be getting a compiler or linker error if that was the problem.  Most likely your environment is set up properly and the problem is in code.

Comment: I think you're right. I got it to work if I put it after certain initialization lines. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the static version of GLEW.

Make sure you `#define GLEW_STATIC` before `#include`ing `glew.h`.