# Trouble with SOIL library linker error using C++

Tags: c++, linker-errors, soil

(Hello, this is my first post, and I am using Dev C++ IDE 5.11)
I included the header, SOIL.h and the linker: -lSOIL.
This program compiles with no problem and runs correctly, but when I **add any function into my code from the SOIL library**, I receive a linker error.
'**recipe for target 'Project1.exe' failed**'
Here is the code from SOIL that causes the linker error:

```
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("container.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
```

(There is probably an easy explanation and answer for this, but I have searched everywhere as I cannot find it.)
Note: I am following a tutorial from the website learnopengl
Here is my makefile.win:

```
# Project: Project1
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11
CPP      = g++.exe
CC       = gcc.exe
WINDRES  = windres.exe
OBJ      = Untitled2.o
LINKOBJ  = Untitled2.o
LIBS     = -L"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib" -L"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/mingw32/lib" -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lopengl32 -lmingw32 -lSOIL
INCS     = -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/include" -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/include" -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include" -I"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++"
BIN      = Project1.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) 
CFLAGS   = $(INCS) 
RM       = rm.exe -f
.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom
all: all-before $(BIN) all-after
clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
Untitled2.o: Untitled2.cpp
    $(CPP) -c Untitled2.cpp -o Untitled2.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Compilation log:

```
Compiling project changes...
--------
- Project Filename: D:\Desktop Files\Programming Stuff\C++\C++ Projects\project examples\etchasketch\Project1.dev
- Compiler Name: MinGW GCC 4.7.2 32-bit Release

Building makefile...
--------
- Filename: D:\Desktop Files\Programming Stuff\C++\C++ Projects\project examples\etchasketch\Makefile.win

Processing makefile...
--------
- Makefile Processor: D:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW32\bin\mingw32-make.exe
- Command: mingw32-make.exe -f "D:\Desktop Files\Programming Stuff\C++\C++ Projects\project examples\etchasketch\Makefile.win" all

g++.exe Untitled2.o -o Project1.exe -L"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib" -L"D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/mingw32/lib" -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lmingw32 -Bstatic -lSOIL

D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x15e): more undefined references to `glGetString@4' follow
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x1d1): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x5e2): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x66a): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x84f): undefined reference to `glDeleteTextures@8'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0xdf8): undefined reference to `glReadPixels@28'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x100d): undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x1427): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x15a8): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x161a): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o):SOIL.c:(.text+0x188c): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D@36'
d:/dev-cpp/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Dev-Cpp/MinGW32/lib/libSOIL.a(SOIL.o): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
d:/dev-cpp/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

D:\Desktop Files\Programming Stuff\C++\C++ Projects\project examples\etchasketch\Makefile.win:25: recipe for target 'Project1.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Project1.exe] Error 1


Compilation results...
--------
- Errors: 1
- Warnings: 0
- Compilation Time: 0.25s
```

Comment: 'recipe for target 'Project1.exe' failed' is not very informative, could you post an earlier error? Also, check that libSOIL is in one of the /lib directories on the LIBS= line.

Comment: The only other error that I get is: id returned 1 exit status. And unfortunately there are no earlier errors. Is it the libsoil.a that should be in /lib directory? That is what is in there now.

Comment: Try `-lsoil` instead of `-lSOIL`. Also .a is a static library, try adding `-Wl,-Bstatic` before `-lsoil`.

Comment: Ok. I tried -lsoil and it failed. I then added -wl and -Bstatic. that gave me the error: 
[Error] unrecognized command line option '-Wl'

Comment: Perhaps just `-Bstatic` if it's linking with ld rather than gcc. Or add `-static` to link everything statically.

Comment: Also, are you sure that there isn't a 'compilation log' or similar in your IDE?

Comment: I found the compilation log. 
It seems to be too long to post in this chat.
I will post it in the original question below the makefile.win section. 
I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: It looks like it cant find opengl. Try this post maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234386/compiling-simple-static-opengl-4-0-program-using-mingw-freeglut-and-glew

Comment: Thanks, it is figured out now. Read the solution. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much Patrick Stewart for helping me figure this out. 
Oddly enough, when I didn't have the -Bstatic, there was the only one error. When I followed what you said about the compilation log, it gave more errors that I did not know were there. I Googled it and found out an answer from this site: 
 http://www.gamedev.net/topic/614336-soil-linker-errors/ 
that the -lSOIL had to be before the -lopengl32.
This is weird in my opinion, but it is a solution.