# Problems with GLEW using MinGW: Undefined reference to '_imp__glewExperimental.'

Tags: c, opengl, linker, glew, glfw

I'm using *GLEW version 1.10.0* with MinGW (Through the CodeBlocks IDE), running on Windows 8. I downloaded the Windows binaries from the GLEW website, and have been linking to the libraries included with that build.

I have a linking problem that I just can't seem to find an answer to. I have followed the installation on the GLEW home page. I have referenced the linker to the glew32.lib, as well as the other required libs such as opengl32 and glu32.

Unfortunately, compiling this code (I'm also using GLFW for context/window management):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int main()
{
GLFWwindow *window;

if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3.0);
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);

if (!window)
{
     glfwTerminate();
     return -1;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

// Initialize GLEW
glewExperimental=TRUE;
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (err!=GLEW_OK)
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize GLEW!");

printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

I get the error:

*undefined reference to *imp*_glewExperimental*

Even though I'm new to C, as far as I understand, this means that I'm referring to something which has no definition, which generally means the library is missing. In this case though, I *have* included the library, and I got no errors whatsoever about the other GLEW references I make, such as *glewInit*, which I feel it should also complain about should it be a problem of missing libraries.

I've tried to search the web but I simply haven't found anything on this problem.

Anyone got any ideas? :)

Thank you all very much for your time. It is much appriciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems I have solved the problem. For anyone who'd like to know, it appears the problem was the pre-build Windows binaries from the GLEW website, because they originate from Visual Studio (they are .lib files). I was using MinGW to do compilation. As soon as I tried to compile GLEW myself using MinGW to create a .a archive, it worked.

There's already a great answer here on stackoverflow on how to compile GLEW for MinGW, and can be found right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005076/building-glew-on-windows-with-mingw).

Comment: Hey! I have an extremely similar problem right now. I compiled GLEW with MinGW using MSYS's `make` successfully, but still I get some 'not found' messages. Do you by any chance remember your compile/link command or can easily reproduce it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, `g++ -o test.exe test.cpp -I include -L lib -D GLEW_STATIC -lglew32 -lopengl32` gives the same error `undefined reference to \`glewInit@0'`. Am I missing any other libraries that need to be linked?

Comment: Alright it turns out I was using the 32 bit version of MinGW with the 64 bit version of glfw. Changing the PATH variable to the 64 bit version of MinGW fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

try to put `#define GLEW_STATIC` on the first line:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

and put `-lglew32s` first in the link libraries table.

codeblocks:

project > build options... > linker settings > add glew32s

then click the up arrow until it get first