# Setting up Opengl (glew)

Tags: opengl

I want to use OpenGL Shading Language(GLSL), with glut.

Develop environment : windows 8 64 bit, visual studio 2012 32 bit

http://www.41post.com/5178/programming/opengl-configuring-glfw-and-glew-in-visual-cplusplus-express

following link, I downloaded glfw and glew. 
And for my visual studio project setting, I chose glew and glfw include derectories, library directories and additional dependencies (I guess)

However, If i run the code, there is **0xc0000007b error**

Why!? T_T

If I add

```
glewInit();
```

then project does not gives any error. However if I add

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Then, **0xc0000007b error** is shown.

Comment: see [Building glew on windows with mingw32](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24839561/2521214) you most likely did not call `glewInit();` after the OpenGL context was created ... Also your gfx card/driver have to support VAO for this ...

Comment: Show your code. Otherwise we are just guessing around here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason : It was due to dll file location.
After I place dll files on folder which contain exe (project file), it works.