# Test Program Using GLEW Crashing on Launch

Tags: windows, opengl, mingw, glew

I am trying to work with OpenGL on Windows in Eclipse using MinGW.
So far I've been able to set up GLFW correctly and now I am trying to load OpenGL pointers with GLEW.

I downloaded the GLEW source and built it using the instructions at [Building glew on windows with mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005076/building-glew-on-windows-with-mingw) and that didn't appear to cause any problems.

I have a test program that I am trying to run. The program runs and opens the window if I comment out the calls to GLEW (lines 32 to 40)

```
/*USE OUR OPENING LIBRARY GLEW TO LOAD OPENGL FUNCTIONS*/
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit();

/*Test that GLEW was loaded by calling the OpenGL function glGenBuffers*/
GLuint vertexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);

printf("%u\n", vertexBuffer);
```

However when I try to make any calls to glew - either set glewExperimental or call glewInit() - the program builds fine but when I run it the program crashes with the error message "HelloGLEW.exe has stopped working". This is the full error message and there are no other error messages.

Can anyone explain/theorise as to the cause of the problem and suggest how to fix them? Or possibly someone had the same problem and can explain how they solved it.

This is the full program code:

```
//Opening Toolkit: GLEW (OpenGL Extention Wrangler)
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

//Window Toolkit: GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* USE GLFW TO CREATE OUR CONTEXT AND WINDOW*/
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello GLEW", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);



    /*USE OUR OPENING LIBRARY GLEW TO LOAD OPENGL FUNCTIONS*/
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    /*Test that GLEW was loaded by calling the OpenGL function glGenBuffers*/
    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);

    printf("%u\n", vertexBuffer);



    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I've linked it with glew32, glu32, glfw3, opengl32 and gdi32 in that order. Here are the compilation commands:

```
g++ "-IC:\\Libraries\\GLFW3\\include" "-IC:\\Libraries\\GLEW\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\Libraries\\GLFW3\\i386\\lib-mingw" "-LC:\\Libraries\\GLEW\\lib" -o HelloGLEW.exe main.o -lglew32 -lglu32 -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32
```

Like I said can anyone explain/theorise as to the cause of the problem and suggest how to fix them? Or possibly someone had the same problem and can explain how they solved it.

Comment: Why aren't you checking `glewInit()`'s return value [like the doc tells you to](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)?

Comment: You're right I should have, I just did a quick copy/paste to get some test code working. I've added it into the program now. But even if I try to debug it the very first thing that happens is the program crashes with the error "HelloGLEW.exe has stopped working".

Comment: Is the GLEW DLL in your exe's current working directory?  Might check with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to make sure all required DLLs are present and accounted for.

Comment: That solved it; I was trying to statically link so I hadn't included the DLL originally.