# multiple definition of `DllMainCRTStartup@12' while building glew on windows with mingw32

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw, glew

I followed this topic: [Building glew on windows with mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005076/building-glew-on-windows-with-mingw/6005262) but something went wrong here:

gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a    -o lib/glew32.dll src/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32

I get this error:

C:\MinGW\dev_lib\glew-2.0.0>gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a -o lib/glew32.dll src/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
src/glew.o:glew.c:(.text+0x28f80): multiple definition of `DllMainCRTStartup@12'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../dllcrt2.o:(.text+0x60): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to link with the `-nostdlib` option like so:

```
gcc -nostdlib -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a    -o lib/glew32.dll src/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
```

Glew defines DllMainCRTStartup which is also defined in the CRT. Hence your problem.

Comment: If this is true, little doubt it is given the linker error, this is beyond incredibly nasty.  -nostdlib is certainly not a valid workaround, very important to get the CRT initialized properly in a DLL.  Proper advice should surely be to only ever use Glew in an EXE project.  That's what it is was made for, a simple way to get started on OpenGL.