# G++. Cannot link library

Tags: opengl, compiler-errors, compilation, linker, g++

I am trying to link a library in order to compile some OpenGL code.

I have the source code i am trying to compile `mytest1.cpp`, and in the same directory, i got a folder called `include` with the header files and another folder called `lib` with all the libraries.

This is what is inside the folder called `lib`:
[image]

So when i run this command, in order to link everything together:

```
g++ -I.\include\ mytest1.cpp -L.\lib\ -llibfreeglut -lopengl32 -lglew32
```

i get this error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -llibfreeglut
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

OS: Windows x64

EDIT: I followed the instructions of Mike Kinghan but unfortunately, this is what i get

```
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined
 reference to `_imp____glewDeleteVertexArrays'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x90): undefined
 reference to `_imp____glewDeleteBuffers'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined
 reference to `_imp____glewBindVertexArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined
 reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xfa): undefined
 reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x123): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x136): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewVertexAttribPointer'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x171): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x195): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x1be): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x1d1): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewVertexAttribPointer'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x20c): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x230): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x273): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBindVertexArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x28f): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBindVertexArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x2db): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewBindVertexArray'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x4d4): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x6e8): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0x859): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xaf1): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewGenVertexArrays'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xb0c): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewGenBuffers'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xbbe): undefine
d reference to `initshaders(unsigned int, char const*)'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xbd7): undefine
d reference to `initshaders(unsigned int, char const*)'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xbf3): undefine
d reference to `initprogram(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xbfd): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewGetUniformLocation'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xc1e): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewGetUniformLocation'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xc3f): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o:mytest1.cpp:(.text+0xc8e): undefine
d reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\U
ser1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyjpOjl.o: bad reloc address 0xd in section `.text$_ZSt
4sqrtf[__ZSt4sqrtf]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I see a downvote but no solutions. If it's so easy, then why don't you offer a solution instead of a downvote? Seems like everything you post will get downvoted these days.

Answer (score 1):

Pehaps you've already pulled off a successful linkage featuring:

```
g++ ... -L.\lib\ ... -lglew32
```

with `.\lib\glew32.lib`, and now you wonder why one like:

```
g++ ... -L.\lib\ ... -llibfreeglut
```

fails to find `.\lib\libfreeglut.a`

Here you have one little snags of working with a Windows port of
a Unix/Linux toolchain ([GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) & [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)).

Classically on *nix systems a file that provides the `name` library for linkage is
is either called `libname.a` (a static library) or `libname.so` (a dynamic library a.k.a shared library).

The option `-lname` instructs the GNU linker to search the specified and
default library directories for either of the files `libname.a` or `libname.so`
and input the first one it finds to the linkage. If it finds both in the same
search directory then it chooses `libname.so`

But this protocol won't do for a Windows port of the toolchain - such as your
`mingw` port - because on Windows the native tradition is to call a static library
`name.lib` and a dynamic library `name.dll`, and a dynamic library always has
the extension `.dll`

So your `mingw` GNU linker with obey `-lname` by searching for
any of the files:

```
libname.a libname.dll name.lib name.dll
```

(and if it's like mine, it prefers a `*.lib` over an `*.a`, and an `*.a` over a `*.dll`
if more than one candidate is found in the same search directory.)

Accordingly your linkage:

```
g++ -I.\include\ mytest1.cpp -L.\lib\ -llibfreeglut -lopengl32 -lglew32
```

would successfuly obey `-lglew32` because `glew32.lib` exists in `.\lib`.
But it will fail on `-llibfreeglut` because none of:

```
liblibfreeglut.a liblibfreeglut.dll libfreeglut.lib libfreeglut.dll
```

exists. Since `libfreeglut.a` *does* exist, use:

```
g++ -I.\include\ mytest1.cpp -L.\lib\ -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -lglew32
```

to solve this specific linkage failure. You don't show us where you expect
the linker to find a file satisfying `-lopengl32`.

**Later... new trouble**

Having got your linkage to find the library `.\lib\libfreeglut.a`
you now have undefined reference linkage errors for numerous references
matching `_imp____glew*` from your own code `mytest1.cpp`. Clearly none
of your code's intended references into the `glew` library are being resolved.

One of the things you need to know when working with Windows `.lib` and `.dll` files is
that a `name.lib` file might be a self-contained static library (of the very same
archive format as a *nix `name.a` static library), or it might be specialized
archive that actually functions as a [DLL import library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-creation)
that stands proxy for a DLL at linktime, the latter being a purely Microsoft
idea. A DLL import library `name.lib` defines symbols of the form `_imp_<symbol>`<sup>1</sup> whose linkage in a program lets the
OS loader provide the program with a pointer to the runtime address of the DLL definition of `<symbol>`,
when `name.dll` is loaded into the process address space.

I am confidently guessing that your `glew32.lib` is not a actually a static library
that you or somebody else built from source with mingw GCC 4.8.1 or an [ABI
compatible compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)
but is a DLL import library from a binary `glew` package you downloaded
that was built with a Microsoft compiler for use with Microsoft compilers.

In general you can't mix object files and/or libraries in the same linkage
that were built by different non-ABI compatible compilers, and MS C/C++ is not ABI
compatible with GCC C/C++.

A name-mangling protocol is part of the ABI. The name mangling protocols of
MS C++ and GCC/Clang C++ are radically different and attempted linkages
that mix the two always fail for undefined reference errors. The name mangling
protocols of MS C and GCC/Clang C diverge a bit, but they do diverge,
and your linkage now falls foul of one of their divergences, attempting to
match the C symbols generated by mingw `g++` from the C header files `<GL/*.h>`
when it compiled `mytest1.cpp` with the C symbols generated by MS C when
it built your `glew32.lib`. Your compiler, for example, outputs an undefined
reference to

```
_imp____glewBindVertexArray
```

which the linkage could only resolve to a symbol defined in `glew32.lib`, but
if you run:

```
>objdump -t glew32.lib | findstr "glewBindVertexArray"
```

in your `mingw` console the closest you will come is:

```
__imp___glewBindVertexArray
```

which is missing one `_`.

You need to build `glew` - a static library or a DLL, or both -
from source with your mingw toolchain, then compile your `mytest1.cpp` (and
any subsequent GLEW program) using the header files of the library you built and
link your program against the library you have built.

You'll find plenty of guidance for "Build glew for mingw" on the internet,
notably on Stackoverflow in the answers to [Building glew on windows with mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6005076/1362568)

---

[1] Where `<symbol>` might itself have one or more leading `_` as a result of C or C++ compiler
[name-mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and possibly a source-code naming convention.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your command but i got so many errors on the compiler that they can't fit in a comment, so i will edit the question.

Comment: Since it's two full days that i am wrestling this compilation unsuccesfully, i am wondering... Can it be the case that i have to recompile FreeGLUT from the source code?

Comment: @user1584421 Answer extended for your new problems.